# Can I declare a dictionary with dynamic array as value type?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I would like to have a function that takes a dictionary of string, array of variant. So it can be called with:

```
  searchDictionary := TDictionary<string, array of variant>;
  searchDictionary.Add('KEY_NAME', ['X01%', '%D01']);
  aValue := TDtoClass.Search(searchDictionary)
```

I am currently achieving this by

```
  searchDictionary := TDictionary<string, TList<variant>>.Create;
  searchDictionary.Add('BIN_NAME', TSearch.Values(['X01%', '%D01']));
```

where Tsearch is a class that exposes:

```
class function TSearch.Values(const arguments: array of variant): TList<variant>;
var
list : TList<variant>;
item: variant;
begin
    list := TList<variant>.Create;
    for item in arguments do
    begin
      list.Add(item);
    end;
    Result := list;           
end;
```

What I would like to do is:

```
searchDictionary.Add('BIN_NAME', ['X01%', '%D01']);
```

instead of:

```
searchDictionary.Add('BIN_NAME', TSearch.Values(['X01%', '%D01']));
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does it not compile (and at which position)?

Comment: .Add( Name: string; a: array of const) ?

Comment: Actually that's a dynamic array rather than an open array. Open arrays only exist as procedure parameters. I've updated the question title.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking how to *declare* the type (which you appear to have already done), or are you asking how to *use* it such that you can add the whole array with a single instruction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While there is no problem in declaring the dictionary, adding values might get somewhat tricky. You can use a special construct to get the required variant array:

```
var
  searchDictionary: TDictionary<string, TArray<variant>>;
begin
  searchDictionary.Add('BIN_NAME', TArray<variant>.Create('X01%', '%D01'));
end;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. A way to add the array elements in one line without the need for a class function (and the additional uses clause entry that would be required). Thanks!

Comment: Is it important for the generic type in the declaration to match the use, or could Reckface's original declaration using `array of Variant` work, too?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, no that won't work. The compiler distinguishes between `TArray<Variant>` and `array of Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a type for array of variant to do more code like you want:

```
type
  TDynamicArrayOfVariant = array of Variant;

var
  searchDictionary: TDictionary<string, TDynamicArrayOfVariant>;
begin
  searchDictionary.Add('BIN_NAME', ['X01%', '%D01']);
end;
```